# How to hide a combobox or label when the form is initially launched

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

[image: Sample image]I have developed a form layout in QT designer. I want to hide a label and combo box when the form is shown up initially or when the application launched. That particular combo box should be shown up only when particular option is selected.

I tried doing this:

```
 if self.comboBox_10.itemText(index) == "Option 1":
        self.label_20.show()
        self.comboBox_11.show()
    elif self.comboBox_10.itemText(index) == "Option 2":
        self.label_20.hide()
        self.comboBox_11.hide()
```

This hides the label and combobox only when the option is selected for the second time not when the form is initially launched.

```
def __init__(self):
self.comboBox_10.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.selectionchange)
def selectionchange(self, index):
if self.comboBox_10.itemText(index) == "Option1":
        self.label_20.show()
        self.comboBox_11.show()
elif self.comboBox_10.itemText(index) == "Option2":
        self.label_20.hide()
        self.comboBox_11.hide()`
```

I want to hide Option 2 when the form is launched initially.

Comment: read [ask] and improve your question

Comment: In your initialization routine after the comboBox has been created and set -- make a direct call to your function selectionchange() giving it the index of the item you set the comboBox up with initially --- oh and yes  "on change" only occurs when the value is changed not when its instantiated so its working properly

Answer (score 0):

First, You'd better understand Qt's Signal and Slot mechanism. Signal means event in Qt, and Slot means signal handler. You should "connect" a "signal" to your "slot".